# Can I open a database on a different server from the PostOpen db script event?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a couple of servers which replicate.  We want to make sure people use the app on the primary server and only use the 2ndary server under certain circumstances.

I added some code in the PostOpen event of the Database Script to check which server the app is open from.  If they're not on the right server a prompt comes up telling them they're on the wrong server and asking if they want to continue or not.

What I'd like to do is if they select 'no', not to continue on the 2ndary server, I'd like to close this db and open the one on the primary server.

I tried using the UI Workspace OpenDatabase but that didn't really work.  It likely can't be done but I thought I'd ask just in case there is a way to do this.

Thanks
clem

Comment: Are the servers clustered?

Answer (score 1):

I have the following code running in an application of mine (stripped down) to achieve what you want to do:

```vb
strServer = "YourMasterServer"
strFilePath = Source.Database.Filepath

Call Source.Close()
Call ws.Opendatabase( strServer, strFilePath)
```

The code is in the PostOpen- Event of the Database.

Comment: Hi Torsten, I tried doing that but it didn't work.  It opens the database on the 2nd server not the primary one.

clem

Comment: Then you did something wrong... Are you sure, you selected the right server for "strServer" ?

Comment: Wouldn't this cause a loop? I.e., user opens on YourMasterServer, PostOpen fires. Code closes window, opens database on YourMasterServer. PostOpen fires. Code closes window, etc...

Comment: It likely would but in my code I check to see what server the db is currently running on.  The idea is that if it's the 2ndary server, then it will close this db and then attempts to open the db from the primary server.  If it's running on the primary server, then it bypasses this.  The problem I see with this code is that it closes the db it's currently running in so how can it get to the next line of the code?  So I tried various versions.

Comment: For example, 

    strServer$ = "PrimaryServer"
    strFilePath$ = Source.Database.Filepath
    
    Dim wssrv1 As New NotesUIWorkspace

    Call Source.Close()
    Call wssrv1.Opendatabase( strServer$, strFilePath$)
Still, it simply seems to open the current db on the 2ndary server not the primary one.